# Weak convergence of normalized random sum

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, weak-convergence, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

Suppose $X_k$ are independent mean 0 random variables with finite positive variance. Can it be true that $\dfrac{S_n}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(S_n)}}$ does not converge weakly? Here $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$.

Almost all the examples I am thinking of, are where the Gaussian limit is not achieved. But is it necessary for the ratio to have a limiting distribution? I guess not, but a hint would be good.

Comment: Just let $X_{n+1}$ have a magnitude that completely dominates the sum of all previous, with a distribution of your choice. So, for example, $\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{Var(S_n)}} \approx \frac{X_n}{\sqrt{Var(X_n)}}$.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $\left(\frac{S_{n}}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}\left(S_{n}\right)}}\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is centered and has variance one, hence this sequence is tight and admits a convergent subsequence. Here the point is that the limit law can be different.

Let $U$ and $V$ be two random variables having variance one and expectation zero; let $\left(Y_i\right)_{i\geqslant 1}$ an independent sequence such that for all $i$, $Y_{2i}$ has the same law as $U$ and $Y_{2i+1}$ the same as $V$. Finally, let $\left(c_i\right)_{i\geqslant 1}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that 
$$
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}c_i^2}{ c_n^2}\to 0
$$
and $X_{i}=c_iY_i$. Then 
$$
\frac{S_{2n}}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}\left(S_{2n}\right)}}\to U\mbox{ and }\frac{S_{2n+1}}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}\left(S_{2n+1}\right)}}\to V.
$$